# How do I launch Metro IE and Metro Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-8, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I installed Windows 8 and I'm not sure how to get to the metro versions of IE or Chrome. The tiles show up in the metro start menu but they launch the desktop applications.

Comment: You have to set the browser to the default browser. So if Chrome is default then you CANNOT use the Metro IE but only the Metro Chrome.  This is well known and a little research goes a long way.

Comment: Did you installed both metro and desktop version on your win8?
Also check what's the default browser as @Ramhound mentioned

Comment: Okay, I had Chrome as the default. Once I set IE as default it did allow me to use the metro version. However, even while Chrome is default it does not load the metro version.

Comment: Also, that is a stupid restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press the gear icon and then "Internet Options" and press "Programs". Make sure Internet Explorer is the default program. Make sure the box "Open internet explorer tiles on the desktop" in NOT checked.