# Can I access the Windows RT Browser in Windows Pro?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, internet-explorer

Can I access the Modern UI version of IE in Windows Pro?

If you can access the Modern UI version of IE how?

Comment: Its not called the "Windows RT Browser" the official unofficial name is the Modern UI version of IE. This can be launched by setting IE as the default browser and launching IE while within the Start Screen.  I suggest you modify your tags to reflect the version of Windows you are using, clarify the technical terms, so your question is clear.

Comment: if you drop the answer i can mark this closed

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/519027/how-do-i-launch-metro-ie-and-metro-chrome

Comment: @Ramhound actually the official name for the fullscreen apps is “immersive”.

Comment: @kinokijuf - I beg to differ.  **If there was an official name I would know about it.**  Modern UI/Windows Store Applications are the closest thing I am aware to an official description/title for those applications.

Comment: @Ramhound Look in the File menu of the desktop mode. It says “open in immersive browser” right there, fifth item from the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer that worked for as per Ramhounds comment.

This can be launched by setting IE as the default browser and launching IE while within the Start Screen.